# Combining polygons and calculating their area (i.e. number of cells) in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a simple raster (created with R-package: raster). Using the function "rasterToPolygons" I get polygons of all raster cells that contain the value "1":

```
library(raster) 
dat = list()
dat$x = seq(1.5, by = 10, len = 10)
dat$y = seq(3.5, by = 10, len = 15)
dat$z = matrix(sample(c(0,1), size = 10*15, replace = T), 10, 15)

r=raster(dat);plot(r)

r_poly = rasterToPolygons(r, fun = function(r) {r == 1}, dissolve = F)
plot(r_poly, add = T)
```

I do not use "dissolve = T" to avoid that all polygons are merged into one big polygon. 
Instead, I wish to obtain a new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in which all polygons that share an edge or a point are combined. Polygons that are clearly separated should be identifiable as individual polygones.
Based on the new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame I would like to analyze the size of the combined polygones as follows:

```
b = extract(r,r_poly_new) # "r_poly_new" contains the combined polygons
str(b)                    # list of clearly separated polygons
tab = lapply(b,table)      
tab
```

My question is twofold:
1) How to combine polygones that share an edge or point? 
2) How to get this information into a format which allows analyzing the areas of the combined polygones?
Thanks very much for your feedback.

Comment: Check out `rgeos::gUnaryUnion` and `rgeos::gUnionCascaded` - I think one of these is what you are after.

Comment: Also +1 for reproducible example. Great first question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could first use `raster::clump()` to identify clusters of connected raster cells and *then* apply `rasterToPolygons()` to "polygonize" those cells. (Do note, though, that each clump's area can be computed directly from the `RasterLayer` without converting it to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, as shown below):

```
library(rgeos) ## For the function gArea

## Clump and polygonize
Rclus <- clump(r)
SPclus <- rasterToPolygons(Rclus, dissolve=TRUE)

## Check that this works
plot(SPclus, col = seq_along(SPclus))

## Get cluster areas from RasterLayer object
transform(data.frame(freq(Rclus)), 
          area = count*prod(res(Rclus)))

## Get cluster areas from SpatialPolygons object
transform(data.frame(SPclus), 
          area = gArea(SPclus, byid=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: @SimonO101 -- The take-home message may be that **raster** and **rgeos** are *both* exceptionally comprehensive and smoothly functioning R packages.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Add `sp` to that list. The triumvirate that rival ArcGIS for features and smash it into the ground for usability.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien -- Thanks a lot! This works great and is exactly what I was looking for! However, I discovered that the last part of the R-code (i.e Get cluster areas from SpatialPolygons object) was not always working properly. Interestingly, (sometimes) the area of the largest cluster from the SpatialPolygons object was overestimated, whereas the cluster areas from RasterLayer object were always estimated correctly (I counted several times ;) ). Again, many thanks for the help! Alex

Comment: I am continuously surprised at how powerful `raster` is.

Answer (score 3):

The `rgeos` package has many polygon manipulation tools. `gUnion` will union together touching polygons:

```
require(rgeos)
uni <- gUnion( r_poly , r_poly )
plot( uni , col = 2 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick reply. However, the problem is that I still get one multipart polygon. What I need are singlepart polygons (in your example: 5 individual polygons). Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexZ yes there is a way to do this. It currently escapes me but I am looking. `rgeos` is very powerful and contains many polygon manipulation tools. Also asking this question on the `r-sig-geo` mailing list will undoubtedly raise a response from those with more know-how than me.

Comment: Dear Simon, Thanks for your reply. I will ask the question on the r-sig-geo mailing list. Best regards, Alex.

Answer (score 3):

`rasterToPolygons()` is a computationally very expensive operation so, assuming the CRS is planar, I would go for:

```
m <- clump(r)
f <- freq(m)
f[,2] <- f[,2] * xres(r) * yres(r)
```

For lon/lat, I would use:

```
a <- area(r)
zonal(a, m, 'sum')
```